# How to add Holo Style Horizontal ProgressBar when minSdkVersion Less than 11?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I build an android project with targetSdkVersion="15" & minSdkVersion="8", then add a horizontal progressbar in activity, but it not holo style when I run this project with android jelly bean.

What can I do?   to edit values-v14 style.xml?

layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/countdown_progressbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:max="30" />
```

values & values-v14 style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light" />
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get the resources for the progessbar. You can get them from  http://android-holo-colors.com/ with the styles.xml file  or use the HoloEverywhere library: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 2):

Use `?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal` instead of `@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal`.

As I understand this, `?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal` is current theme styled progress bar style whereas `@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal` is just plain android progress bar style.

The code should look like:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/countdown_progressbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:max="30" />
```

Comment: Please add clarification as to how and why this would help.